# Charting with Visual Studio 2010 and exporting to Excel

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2010, excel, .net-4.0, charts

Im doing a project with .Net 4.0, Visual Studio 2010 and Visual Basic .Net.

I needed to add a Chart (the new one included by default in .Net 4.0) that represents temperatures evolving with time, so I added the drawing points in the elapsed event of the timer every second.

The graph is doing somewhat ok, but I need another functionality, and this is, every time I stop the timer, save the graph in an excel (.XLS or .XLSX) file. As by default the chart provides with a collection of the type "System.Windows.Forms.DataVisualization.Charting.DataPointCollection", I would like to know if there is a way to create an xml and put the info of those collections in the excel file.

I have looked around but I didn't find any similar example, last thing im thinking about is to use an iterative way to manually write in the excel file, but maybe its too much time consuming as the iteration will be of several thousands seconds.

Any idea or anyone that had a similar problem and can help?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms262200%28v=office.14%29

Answer (score 0):

If you're trying to generate charts into an Excel document, let me point you to [Officewriter](http://www.officewriter.com/officewriter-api.aspx%20OfficeWriter). It has a full charting API. The underlying Excel Charting xml is pretty complicated, especially for the newer OOXML versions. The older .xls BIFF is downright scary. What you could do is figure out what chart you're trying to generate, and then use the ExcelWriter charting API to build that exact chart and save it out to a file. Should be relatively painless. You can grab an evaluation for free from [here](http://www.officewriter.com/officewriter-free-evaluation.aspx%20here) to see if it works for you. As a disclaimer, I'm one of the engineers who bled to build the charting API for the latest version.

Comment: Thanks for the aswer. Specifically I only need to write the collection of points, it's that the (x,y) coordinates that the chart in visual studio generates, as it will be interpretated again by the program later, the excel file with the coordinates is only for the client purposes and I don't need to do anything there